# How to install Mongodb PHP extension in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to use Mongodb with PHP. For this I thought that `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` (which is enough for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) would be enough but I was wrong. I'm getting error like this `E: Unable to locate package php5-mongo`.

I've just upgraded to `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and want to use `mongodb` with `PHP`. Running PHP version is `PHP Version 7.0.4-7ubuntu2`.

So what can I do to solve this?

Comment: umm, if you're running php7, why are you trying to install a php5 package? perhaps it's php7-mongo?

Comment: @MarcB, I've also tried `sudo apt-get install php7-mongo` this but not get any positive result

Comment: so go look around the 16.04lts repository and figure out what the package name is. or even something like `dpkg -L|grep -i mongo`

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you are a bit out of luck at the moment. The current situation is that there are two MongoDB extensions:

- "php-mongo", which is the "old" one; This extension supports up to PHP 5.*, but not PHP7. Only bug fixes are planned for it;
- "php-mongodb", which is the "new" one; This extension supports PHP5 as well as PHP7;

Now the problem is that the new one is not compatible with the old one, as their whole internals are completely different. Unfortunately there are very few places where examples using the new one's syntax is used, as absolute majority of Mongo-related code is written using the old extension.

As it stands at the moment, if you have moved on to PHP7 your only option is to use the "new" extension, which in turn means that your previous code will stop working.

I've seen couple attempts to create a polyfill for making the migration those two possible (example: https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter), however as I haven't tried it myself I can't tell how well it works.

It seems that this library http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/ is supposed to cover the gap - after giving it a shot I believe it should cover majority of the "old" functionality without updating code too much.

Answer (score 0):

If some of you are still wondering to use a simple wrapper to the new library as said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48086676/2569789
I'm maintaining one for this purpose and you can find it here: https://github.com/ThomasSquall/PHP7MongoDriver

It covers just a few methods at the today's date but I'm going to improve it constantly and I hope would like to contribute too :)