# problems with php7 mongo query findOne

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I've ubuntu 16.04, php7 and mongo.

After update the system, my code doesn't work... I've a new version of php.

Before update, my code was:

```
  // connect
  $m = new MongoClient();
  // select a database
  $db = $m->clients;
  // select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
  $collection = $db->suscriptions;
  // Check if exists in DB
  $query = array('email' => $email);
  $cursor = $collection->findOne($query);
```

After update, I changed the connection as indicated by the php documentation, but I can't do any query... 
This is my code, if I remove the last line, the code works:

```
  // connect
  $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  // select a database
  $db = $m->clients;
  // select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
  $collection = $db->suscriptions;
  // Check if exists in DB
  $query = array('email' => $email);
  // Problem
  $cursor = $collection->findOne($query);
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usage of manager api is incorrect.

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter= array('email' => $email);
$options = array(
  'limit' => 1
);
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows = $m->executeQuery('clients.suscriptions', $query);
```

Alternatively, you should install the library through [composer](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/install-php-library/) which provides similar syntax as old api.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$m= new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
$db = $m->clients;
$collection = $db->suscriptions;
$query = array('email' => $email);
$document = $collection->findOne($query);
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#find-one-document

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering to use a simple wrapper between the new Mongo Library and PHP7 I'm maintaining one on my GitHub.

https://github.com/ThomasSquall/PHP7MongoDriver

Also if you want to contribute to the repository itself you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just spent some time thinking this wasn't working when it was by trying to `print_r` the result directly, if just testing code then the cursor has to be converted to an array to be visible as so:

```
$result = $this->OMongo->executeQuery("db.collection", $query);
print_r(iterator_to_array($result), false);
```